# aws lambda SES function timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, serverless-framework, amazon-ses

I am using nodejs version 8.1 and severless framework

in my serverless.yml I have:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  region: eu-west-1
  iamRoleStatements:
  - Effect: "Allow"
    Action:
      - "ses:GetIdentityVerificationAttributes"
    Resource: "*"
```

and my lambda looks like this:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var ses = new AWS.SES({
  region: 'eu-west-1'
});
module.exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
 context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
 let identityVerif = await ses.getIdentityVerificationAttributes({Identities: ['email']}).promise();
}
```

I don't understand why the getIdentity function is never executed.
The function exit with a timeout.

Comment: It's an async call, so most likely a result is never returned and the function times out while waiting. Enable some logging and check to see if that request is being made and responded to.

Comment: if i log something before getIdentity it is log, but something after the function is not log. I have tried to set a timeout of 25 seconds but same thing happen.

Comment: You need logs on the server side of things, not the client side

Comment: I don't understand, I put my log in my lambda function just before the line getIdentityVerificationAttributes, and one log after getIdentityVerificationAttributes. First one is executed but not the second log.

Comment: I forgot to mention that my lambda is running inside a vpc, might that be the problem ?

Comment: You need logs on the service that responds to the call, not the one that makes it. Start here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're waiting for the response of an async call, and it's likely that you aren't getting one. Check the [SES API logs in CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html) to make sure that the request is actually being made. It sounds like your lamdba function can't access SES, which would happen if you are running it in a VPC. You would need to add a NAT Gateway to the VPC. Consider moving your lambda outside of your VPC. [Here is a guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html#lambda-vpc) to help determine the tradeoffs.

Comment: I saw something called private link, is this available for SES? or can I only achieve this with NAT Gateway? I am using my lambda in a VPC because i need to access my database with vpc peering.

Comment: Private Link is not available for SES. Maybe you can  move the SES-related ops to a function outside the VPC and pass required information to it via API Gateway if you don't want to set up NAT

Comment: PrivateLink is available for SES as of Apr. 2020, but I haven't been able to get it to work. [announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-simple-email-service-ses-for-vpc-endpoints/)

Comment: Same i have been trying for hours to make SES work from lambda which is in VPC. But getting timeout.